# In boost::signals, what is the difference between 'slot_type' and 'slot_function_type'?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

Towards the end of [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3161780) for the boost::signals library, under the heading "Passing slots" a type called 'slot_type' is used to pass the desired slot function to be connected to the signal. But then, in the [next example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3162554), they do apparently the same thing using a type called 'slot_function_type'.

I haven't been able to work out what the difference is between these two things.

When should I use 'slot_type' and when should I use 'slot_function_type'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slot_type` is `boost::slot<slot_function_type>`.

For a signal `boost::signal<R(T1, T2, ... TN)>`, `slot_function_type` is the type-erased function object class `boost::functionN<R, T1, T2, ... TN>`, equivalent to `std::function<R(T1, T2, ... TN)>`, so it can hold any object supporting the signal's call signature (e.g. function pointers, callable objects, `boost::bind`, etc.).

`slot_type` contains and has an implicit constructor from `slot_function_type`, but it also contains the machinery for automatic connection management through `boost::trackable` (see [Automatic connection management (Intermediate)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3162121) in the tutorial).

You want to use `slot_type` unless you have some specific reason to use `slot_function_type`, as this will ensure that if you ever need to use automatic connection management it will just work.  `slot_type` has a templated implicit constructor, so it's OK to use anywhere `slot_function_type` would work for passing to `boost::signal::connect()`.